# how to set enableAutoStart on youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am creating web application using `youtube-api` , if i am click start streaming on my encoding software , but not setting manually on live control, i found [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.enableAutoStart) , but i am not sure how to use this

this is my piece code :

```
$broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($_POST['date_start']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime($_POST['date_end']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setDescription($_POST['descrip']);
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus('private');

    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    $broadcastContent = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
    $broadcastContent->setEnableAutoStart(true);
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',
        $broadcastInsert, array());
```

this code work perfectly add event stream but at `$broadcastContent` this code not set `true` for `enableAutoStart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah litle tricky here , edit your code like this:

```
$broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$broadcastSnippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
$broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($_POST['date_start']);
$broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime($_POST['date_end']);
$broadcastSnippet->setDescription($_POST['descrip']);
$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
$status->setPrivacyStatus('private');

$broadcastContent = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
$broadcastContent->setEnableAutoStart(true);

$broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
$broadcastInsert->setContentDetails($broadcastContent); 
$broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
$broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
$broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status,contentDetails',
    $broadcastInsert, array());
```